# When use Google Calendar Api JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "https://accounts.google.com" from accessing a frame with origin "http://192.168.5.102:8100".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of "https", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "http". Protocols must match.

i cant understand how to solve this error,

this error comming from following script

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=checkAuth">
```

and "checkAuth" function is as follow

```
function checkAuth() {
  console.log("her")
  gapi.auth.authorize(
    {
      'client_id': CLIENT_ID,
      'scope': SCOPES.join(' '),
      'immediate': true
    }, handleAuthResult);
}

/**
 * Handle response from authorization server.
 *
 * @param {Object} authResult Authorization result.
 */
function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
  var authorizeDiv = document.getElementById('authorize-div');
  if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
    // Hide auth UI, then load client library.
    authorizeDiv.style.display = 'none';
    loadCalendarApi();
  } else {
    // Show auth UI, allowing the user to initiate authorization by
    // clicking authorize button.
    authorizeDiv.style.display = 'inline';
  }
}
```

please solve this error, thank you

Comment: Try changing `https` to `http` or enable `https` on your domain

Comment: <script src="http://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=checkAuth"></script> (https to http) but generate same error

Comment: Because it auto-redirects to https

Comment: then how can i solve this error bro..

Comment: Enable HTTPS on your site or copy that script to your server (don't know if that would work)